# Echoing awk output to file to remove duplicates has strange output

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sh

I made a small shell script to try to remove duplicate entries (lines) from a text file. When the script is ran and the file has three lines, all identical, a strange output occurs.

The shell script is ran on an Ubuntu distribution.

**The contents of my text file:**

```
one
one
one
```

The script I am running to remove duplicates:

```
echo -e $(awk '!a[$0]++' /test/test.txt) > /test/test.txt
```

The *awk* is intended to delete duplicates, while the *echo* is intended to output it to a file.

Upon running my script, **I receive the following output in the file**:

```
one
 one
```

It should also be noted that there is an additional newline after the second line, and a space at the start of the second line.

Comment: You just need `awk '!a[$0]++' /test/test.txt > /test/newtest.txt`, alone. You don't have to `echo` it. Also ensure your input file does not have any [DOS endings](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~krueger/csc209h/tut/line-endings.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing to a file at the same time that you are reading from it usually leads to disaster.

If you have GNU awk, then use the `-i inplace` option:

```
$ cat text
one
one
one
$ gawk -i inplace '!a[$0]++' text
$ cat text
one
```

If you have BSD awk, then use:

```
awk '!a[$0]++' text >tmp && mv tmp text
```

Alternatively, if you have `sponge` installed:

```
awk '!a[$0]++' text | sponge text
```

`sponge` does not update the file until the pipeline has finished reading and processing it.